# Reference an ID from one Javascript file that was created in another Javascript file

Tags: javascript, html, css-selectors, dom-events

I am stuck with an issue in my Javascript. I have created a file that uses ID'S to solve an equation. I created the ID's in a Javascript file and in another file I used these ID's for the equation. However, when I display my files in Firefox, I get the following issue in the console:

> Uncaught TypeError: document.querySelector(...) is null
> windChill http‍://127.0.0.1:5500/js/windchill.js:2
> EventHandlerNonNull* http‍://127.0.0.1:5500/js/windchill.js:12

Here is the code I created for this, in their perpective files:
(also ignore the JSON file I am referencing. I will work on that part once I solve the ID parts)

js/preston.js

```
   window.addEventListener("load", (event)=>{ 
     const apiURL = "https://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?id=5604473&appid=6d1d830097a2c0bac1aba2337d0139e6";
      divWeatherdata = document.querySelector('div.weather-summary-paragraph');
      fetch(apiURL)
        .then((response) => response.json())
        .then((jsObject) => {
          console.log(jsObject);
          let mainList = document.createElement("ul");
          mainList.className = "list2";
          let mainWeather = document.createElement("p");
          mainWeather.textContent = "Sunny";
          let TempSpan = document.createElement("span");
          let currentTemp = document.createElement("p");
          currentTemp.setAttribute("id", "text1");
          currentTemp.textContent = "40";
          let windChill = document.createElement("p");
          windChill.textContent = "chill";
          windChill.setAttribute("id", "chills");
          let humidity = document.createElement("p");
          humidity.textContent = "54";
          let windSpeedWrapper = document.createElement("span");
          let windSpeed = document.createElement("p");
          windSpeed.textContent = "5";
          windSpeed.setAttribute("id", "text2");
          mainList.appendChild(mainWeather);
          TempSpan.appendChild(currentTemp);
          mainList.appendChild(TempSpan);
          mainList.appendChild(windChill);
          mainList.appendChild(humidity);
          mainList.appendChild(windSpeedWrapper);
          windSpeedWrapper.appendChild(windSpeed);
          divWeatherdata.appendChild(mainList);
        });
    
    })
```

js/windchill.js

```
function windChill(){
var t = document.querySelector("#text1").innerHTML;
var s = document.querySelector("#text2").innerHTML;
var f = Math.round(35.74 + (0.6215 * t) - (35.75 * Math.pow(s,0.16)) + 0.4275 * t * Math.pow(s,0.16));
if ( t <= 50 && s > 3){
    document.getElementById("chills").innerHTML=f + "&#8457";
}
else{
    document.getElementById("chills").innerHTML="N/A";
} 
        }
window.onload=windChill ;
```

Comment: Which file is executed first?

Comment: Preston/js is. It is the first file to appear in the head.

Comment: Can you point me where in the preston code you are apending all the created content to the DOM?

Comment: Sure. Wherever I have setAttribute, I add and ID to each "p" element, which is then referanced in the second file, but the console is acting as if there is no such thing. I had tested it when writing it in the html and the windchill file processes it just fine, but when the html is written through javascript, thats when I have issues.

Comment: You've added the contents of `preston.js` to be triggered on `load`, and you also execute `windchill` onload.  I.e., those get triggered at the same time.  `windchill` runs almost instantly, whereas the `fetch` in preston.js will be delayed waiting for a response. You create a bunch of elements AFTER that response.  I.e., `windchill` is probably referencing elements that haven't been created yet. Why not execute `windchill()` at the end of your `.then` after the fetch, and remove `window.onload=windchill;`

Comment: Thank you! I will attempt to implement this now.

Comment: It worked! thank you so much for your help.